# POST not working with Node and Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a POST request from Angular Factory to Node.

**Angular Factory -**

```
    function saveUser(userObject){
        var createUser = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'CreateUser',
            data: userObject,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });

        return createUser.then(callSuccess, callError);
    }
```

**Node-**

```
function create(){
    app.post('/CreateUser', urlEncodedParser, function(request, response){
        var userData = {
            firstName : request.body.firstName,
            lastName : request.body.lastName,
            email : request.body.email,
            password : request.body.password,
            role : request.body.role
        };
        console.log(request);
        console.log(userData);

       dbOpperations.saveData(userData, 'UserTable');
    });
}
```

The call is made but I get `response.body = {}`

Comment: could be due to the reason that you're not returning any desired data from 'node'

Comment: it seems that you are not returning anything from the `POST` request. Try to add `response.send('User is created')` in the success callback of  `dbOperations` .

Comment: Does your `console.log()` works ?

Comment: Yes, `console.log()` works. I'm able to see the 'request.body' as empty object.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I'm getting empty object for `request.body` (instead of `response.body`). Additionally when I'm using Postman tool it works, but doesn't  works when called from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an empty response because you are not returning anything from node.

please use response.send()

```
response.send('success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help.

I'm able to POST the data and save on db.

I missed to use `app.use(bodyParser.json());`